# mc.yandex.ru - Что это?

Tags: веб-программирование

mc.yandex.ru — что это за сервис, может кто знает?  Я искал подобный сервис у них на сайте, но ничего похожего не нашел.  Я знаю точно, что этот сервис относится к веб-разработке.

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего тематике сайта.

Comment: @alexander barakin Тематика  сообщества связанна  с программированием, а так-же веб-разработкой. mc.yandex.ru - технология которая может используется в веб-разработки. Почему  вы полагаете что тематика сообщества не соответствует заданному вопросу? Я голосую против закрытия этого вопроса, так как этот вопрос полностью отвечает всем требованиям согласно правилам сообщества.

Comment: к веб-разработке много чего относится. в принципе, любой сайт, доступный (или даже недоступный) из интернета, прямо и непосредственно относится к веб-разработке (и не только к веб-разработке, кстати). // не соответствует тематике базы знаний вопрос: «а что это за сайт имярек?»

Comment: @alexander barakin  Если вопрос относится к соответствующий тематике этого сообщества, то почему вы голосовали против? И `// не соответствует тематике базы знаний вопрос: «а что это за сайт имярек?»` - подобный вопрос явно не относится к веб-разработке. А сравнивать ваш вопрос с моим, не корректно. Потому что, суть моего вопроса не общего информационного характера, а профильного,  об определённом веб-сервисе, который предоставляется и используется исключительно веб-разработчиками.  Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов это внутренняя техническая деталь Яндекса, которая всё равно не используется напрямую (а только фигурирует в коде счётчиков метрики) и от знания назначения этого домена особой пользы нет. Поэтому как отдельный пункт в "базе знаний" (которую мы тут собираем) он слабоват.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Этот домен используется [Яндекс.Метрикой](//yandex.ru/support/metrika/)

URL вида `//mc.yandex.ru/watch/некое_число` отдают 1-пиксельную GIF-картинку, которая сама по себе бесполезна. Но ценность представляет **запрос**, а не ответ на него.

Яндекс собирает данные из запросов и считает по полученным данным статистику. Такой способ сбора статистики работает и без JS! От него спасёт разве что отключение отображения картинок в браузере.

А на [`//mc.yandex.ru/metrika/watch.js`](//mc.yandex.ru/metrika/watch.js) находится JS-часть трекера, которая умеет собирать побольше данных.

Comment: Интересно было бы почитать, об ограничениях на сбор подобной статистики, касательно законодательства РФ.

Comment: @edem ограничения на действия такого рода, насколько мне известно, действуют только для **персональных данных**. Яндекс [в условиях использования Метрики](https://yandex.ru/legal/metrica_termsofuse/) от этого открещивается, мол, система автоматизированная, данные не привязываются к конкретным лицам, а пользователи Метрики обязуются соблюдать правила обработки персональных данных.

Comment: @D-side спасибо за ответ. довольно интересно

Comment: @D-side  спасибо.